# symfony request Acceptable content type

Tags: php, symfony, request

For my unit test I create a`symfony\component\httpfoundation\request` like this :

```
$request = Request::create('http://localhost:8080/location', 'POST');
$request->headers->set('Accept:', 'application/json'); 
$request->request->set('address', 'address');
$request->request->set('name', 'name');
```

but when I do :

```
echo $request->headers->get('Accept');
```

I get :

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Why I don't get :

```
application/json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `Accept:` but reading `Accept`. Remove colon character when setting